# Is there a proxy for the Steam Web API?

Tags: steam

I'm making a small spreadsheet that tracks the amount of kills my wrench's eaten over time in TF2.  So far I've been manually copy pasting fields from the TF2 window, but hey, Steam does have some API I could consume, and Google Spreadsheets can consume XML too. This number I'm tracking should also be exposed by the [`GetPlayerItems`](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI/GetPlayerItems) route, so I should be golden!

Except [the Steam Web API *requires* a domain-bound authorization key](http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey) (!). I don't own docs.google.com, so I can't get one. Thus, I cannot make the API call.

Is there some kind of API proxy service for the Steam Web API so that I can query the API without having to buy a whole damn domain for such a simple use case? ...or do I have to resort to scraping middle men such as tf2b.com?

Answer (score 5):

As [Thomas McDonald](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/821/thomas-mcdonald?tab=accounts) [noted](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2137103#2137103), while your (one) API key is bound to a domain, **your requests do actually not need to be made from there.** So, *no proxy service is necessary.*

Since I already do have a blog, I registered an API with that site, and now I can happily consume the API without resorting to scraping.

Comment: Thomas, when you'll eventually bother to answer this question, I'll happily delete this and accept yours.

Comment: Oh, and if you're curious, the Google Spredsheets formula I used is: `=importxml("http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?SteamID=76561197988192258&key=redacted&format=xml", "//item[id=434044620]//attribute[defindex=214]/value")`. Adapt to your use case as necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You can request a key for a [No-IP](http://www.no-ip.com/) subdomain and do your petitions from your own computer.

Comment: I'd find it easier, then, to register a domain from the Google AppEngine... it just seems very much like overkill.

Comment: No-IP is free, and you only need a web server (like XAMPP) running in your computer. So you start your local server, update your No-IP account to point to your current IP, launch your local script and it's done.

Comment: Tturns out it's actually unnecessary to get any DNS name :)